# Open Type MXBean issue

Tags: java, javabeans, jmx, java-7, mbeans

While starting MXBean, i am getting error mentioning Method SampleServiceMXBean.register has parameter or return type that cannot be translated into an open type. As per the error message says its clear that my MXBean is not able to catch up the composite classes.

Explaining the things in a better way : 
Here is my MXBean Interface Code

```
 public interface SampleServiceMXBean {
      public boolean register(FileInfo fi) throws IOException;   //FileInfo is a not Open Type(Composite)
 }
```

Starting the MXBean Server Code

```
 MBeanServer beanServer= ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
 ObjectName sampleName = new ObjectName("com.me.core.services:fileExt=SampleService");
 beanServer.registerMBean(sampleService,sampleName);
```

Now, as far as i have read it's said that mxbean supports composite type parameter, not like means which only support the open types then why i am getting this error? I guess it's not the proper way to use Composite type object. Any idea how to initiate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have forget to serialize those objects. Try doing that, coz as far i know open type is properly handled by MXBEAN

Answer (score 0):

If FileInfo is a Java bean then JMX should be able to handle it. However if you are making the data members final and setting them via the constructor you need to use the ConstructorParameters  annotation e.g.

```
public class FileInfo {
   private final String filename;
   private final String filetype;

   @ConstructorProperties({"filename", "filetype"})
   public FileInfo(String filename, String filetype) {
      this.filename = filename;
      this.filetype = filetype;
   }

   public String getFilename() {
     return filename;
   }

   public String getFiletype() {
     return filetype;
   }
}
```